# Method with param name of table return BaseModel from diferente table

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want create an endpoint with two parâmetros, table name and filter. Then create a query that Access to datacontext table in parameter and filter on where clause and select in base modelo.
Example
BaseModel : id, name
Table a : idA, CodeA, nameA
Table b : idB, CodeB, nameB

Method getlist( Table a, null) that return all from table A mapped to base model

Anyone have any idea how to create This on c# .net Core 6?

Thanks

The method should return lista of BaseModel mapped from the table sended on parameter

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please specify more details about your question, and try to use English as that is recommended. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great if you provide more details. However, something like this might be a good start:

```
    [ApiController]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DataContext_context;

        public MyController(DataContextcontext)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("{tableName}")]
        public IActionResult GetList(string tableName, string? filter=null)
        {
            var entityType = _context.Model.FindEntityType(tableName);
            if (entityType == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var query = _context.Set(entityType.ClrType).AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
            {
                // Apply filter to the query
                query = query.Where($"{entityType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties.First().Name} = {filter}");
            }

            // Map to base model
            var result = query.Select(entity =>
                entityType.ClrType.Name switch
                {
                    nameof(TableA) => new BaseModel { Id = entity.IdA, Name = entity.NameA },
                    nameof(TableB) => new BaseModel { Id = entity.IdB, Name = entity.NameB },
                    _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"Table {tableName} is not supported")
                });

            return Ok(result.ToList());
        }
    }
```